# How can I write the javascript equivalent for cURL code?

Tags: javascript, curl, button

I have the following input field:

```
 <input id="dataRequest" type="text" method="POST" border=None value=""/>
```

and developed code that responds to the following cURL command.

```
curl -v --insecure -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST -d 'dataRequest=demo1' https://localhost:443
```

Entering a value into the input field does not work.

Question 1: Why does the cURL code work when filling in the field does not?

Question 2: I am trying to use Javascript to create a button that will submit the equivalent command (to cURL) when pressed.

This is what I have so far, but it does not work (nothing happens).

```
<button onclick="runDemo1()" name="button1" value="demo1">

<script>
function runDemo1() {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("dataRequest", "demo1");
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let page = window.location.host;
  xhr.open("POST", page, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.send(formData);
}
</script>
```

Comment: There's more involved in using [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://javascript.info/xmlhttprequest). The `--insecure` flag isn't convertable to Javascript.

Comment: https://reqbin.com/req/c-w7oitglz/convert-curl-to-http-request There is a website that you can maybe try.

Comment: xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      console.log(xhr.status);
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
   }};

var data = "dataRequest=demo1";

xhr.send(data);

Comment: If you can use packages, might want to check axios (https://github.com/axios/axios) or ky (https://github.com/sindresorhus/ky). Makes things a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your curl command and put it into this website: https://reqbin.com/req/c-w7oitglz/convert-curl-to-http-request

You can change the url from `google` to your `localhost`

```js
var url = "https://google.com";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url);

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      console.log(xhr.status);
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
   }};

var data = "dataRequest=demo1";

xhr.send(data);
```

Comment: Grant, Thank you!  I have learned a lot from this. Unfortunately, it does not work in my case.  I think this is because of the differences between http: and https: (the --insecure tag in the cURL command)  But that is a different question.